# Rewriting Query String URL in htaccess with 301 Redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, query-string

I have tried to find a solution to my problem in the other asked questions on Stackoverflow, but though there a lot of such questions answered for the exact same question yet it is different because I am asking as to how I should define more than two query strings in the ReWrite Condition,

I am trying to do a 301 redirect on a query string URL:

> http://abc.com/index.php?arg1=abc&arg2=abc

to mask it as

> http://abc.com/prettified_url

,and have tried using the following code in htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^http://abc.com/index.php?arg1=abc&arg2=abc$ /prettified_url  [R=301,L,NC]
```

have also tried using:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^.*abc\.com
    RewriteRule .? - [S=2]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^index.php
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^arg1=abc [NC]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} arg2=abc [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /prettified_url [R=301,L]

    RewriteRule .? - [S=1]
    RewriteRule - -
```

have also tried using the following code in the query string ReWrite Condition:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^arg1=abc&arg2=abc [NC]
```

Though, I am not able to see it being redirected to **/prettified_url**.

Comment: my second attempt with query string in a composite form was successful, it was not working because of the browser cache, when I ran the rules in a new browser then the code worked perfectly..

Answer (score 0):

Try with below one :

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^arg1=abc&arg2=abc
RewriteRule (.*) http://abc.com/prettified_url? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: have mentioned in the question itself about using the same logic, but that doesn't work

Comment: You had used [NC] instead of [L,R 301] and ReqriteRule was missing, so i added the above. Thanks

Comment: yep.. tried using this also, but it doesn't work, btw [NC] simply allows to check the args value without being case-sensitive, so why should it help if we eliminate the NC tag?

Comment: no issue with [NC], but you had not added [L,R=301] which denotes 301 redirection of the page

Comment: anyway, which types of error you are getting? Have you also added htaccess for displaying page for http://abc.com/prettified_url?

Comment: still not able to get it as I have written `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /prettified_url [R=301,L]`, and I have not mentioned the display page for the pretty url but it should display the new url in the browser with error message that no page found for abc.com/prettified_url

Comment: it will not display no page found error if you have not written any code for displaying any page for abc.com/prettified_url, let's say you want to show url.php page at abc.com/prettified_url, then just edit above code with RewriteRule (.*) http://abc.com/url.php [L,R=301], it will succeed.